# HTTPS for every page except for feeds

Tags: https, feedburner, feed

Our site has a persistent login form on every page of the site, so of course we need to keep every page served over SSL. However, we've since discovered that Feedburner doesn't like secure feeds.

Is there a way to deliver the entire site via https, except for "http://nplusonemag.com/feed"?  .htaccess? Action hook?

Edit: I should have shared my .htaccess rules.  These are obviously not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(feed|robots\.txt|favicon.ico) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://nplusonemag.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force non-SSL for certain URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(feed|robots\.txt|favicon.ico)$ http://nplusonemag.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fully-ssl-enabled-site-ok-wexception-of-feedburner?replies=7

Comment: @jeffatrackaid, Can you put this as an answer? I'll try it later and if it works, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. I use rewrite rules to serve my WP blogs over TLS/SSL only. In wordpress I set the url to https:// as well. Might be worth a try to set the blog url to http// and create a rewrite rule (apache/nginx) to use https except the url contains /feed. Not tested.

Comment: Thank you...Please see the edit to my question above wherein I've provided the current .htaccess rules (which do not work). The current blog URL is set to https://. I'm not sure how I'd leverage the rewrite rules to do what you suggest. Do you mean WP's rewrite rules, or those in .htaccess?

Comment: I would solve it using the webserver rewrite rules (.htaccess in your case) because it will not involve php and I always try to avoid extra workload in wordpress. However it will work with wordpress rewrite rules as well.